# Mock an Entity DbContext Insert

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, moq, xunit

I am using **Xunit** & **Moq**. I want to be able to mock an insert into a table. This way the record doesn't actually populate the table, but the unit test can verify that an insert was successful. Using the real DbContext, the unit test works for method **Add_Works()** below. When I try to us Mock, in **Add_WantToWork()**, I get the error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The failure is happening on **Context.Set().Add(entity)** in the **ARepository** class, also shown below. It is called by **uw.Table1.Add(_table1)**.

```
public class UnitTestClass
{
    private readonly Table1 _table1 = new Table1()
    {
        TypeId = 4,
        Name = "TestAutomation",
        Description = "Test Automation",
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    [Fact]
    public void Add_Works()
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        using (var uw = new UnitOfWork(new PortalDbContext()))
        {
            uw.Table1.Add(_table1);
            rowsAffected = uw.Commit();
        }

        Assert.Equal(1, rowsAffected);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Add_WantToWork()
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        var mockContext = new Mock<TestDbContext>();

        using (var uw = new UnitOfWork(mockContext.Object))
        {
            uw.Table1.Add(_table1);
            rowsAffected = uw.Commit();
        }

        Assert.Equal(1, rowsAffected);
    }
}

public abstract class ARepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    protected ARepository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using the EntityFramework, you should be able to find some libraries which allow you to mock the DBContext.

Comment: I am able to mock the DbContext. My issue is when I try to add an object to the mocked DbContext.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the EntityFrameworkMock library, available on [GitHub](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-mock) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkMock/). It is based on Moq so you can use the known Setup and Verify methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is you are mocking the object but no the methods for the object.
it would be something like this :

```
mockContext.Setup(p => p.Set<Table1>().Add(It.IsAny<Table1>())).Returns(_table1);
```

that way the mock will create an instance of the dbSet and will return what ever you want

Comment: This worked. Thanks. `mockContext.Setup(p => p.Set<Table1>().Add(It.IsAny<Table1>())).Returns(_table1);`

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've had experience only mocking that it happens, not that the database took the record. That falls into the realm of integration tests which is out of my expertise. I've used [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) in the past to accomplish a mock.

```
[TestMethod] 
    public void CreateBlog_saves_a_blog_via_context() 
    { 
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>(); 

        var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>(); 
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object); 

        var service = new BlogService(mockContext.Object); 
        service.AddBlog("ADO.NET Blog", "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet"); 

        mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Blog>()), Times.Once()); 
        mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once()); 
    }
```

notice the following lines. These simply verify that the add method is called and save changes was called. Would this be sufficient in solving your challenge?

```
mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Blog>()), Times.Once()); 
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
```

Comment: System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code. Message=Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.Table1s. I got this error on `mockContext.Setup(m => m.Table1s).Returns(mockSet.Object)`